# add observation count to aggregation with data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a table like this one:

```
set.seed(1234)
sportset<-data.table(sport=rep(c("football"),50),
position=rep(c("f","m","d","gk","w"),c("10","7","11","13","9")),
height=rnorm(10,180,13))
```

And I want to calculate the mean of `height`by sport and position. So I used:

```
sportset[,lapply(.SD,mean),by=.(sport,position),.SDcols=c("height")]

      sport position   height
1: football        f 182.5153
2: football        m 186.0845
3: football        d 181.3569
4: football       gk 181.5860
5: football        w 182.4974
```

I would also like to add an extra column with the number of observations used for each aggregation, like this:

```
      sport position   height    obs
1: football        f 182.5153    10
2: football        m 186.0845     7
3: football        d 181.3569    13
4: football       gk 181.5860    11
5: football        w 182.4974     9
```

Do I need to chain it to the original expression, or can it be integrated in the aggregation function and how would I do that?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `c` to concatenate the `list` elements

```
sportset[,c(lapply(.SD,mean),list(obs = .N)),by=.(sport,position),.SDcols= "height"]
#      sport position   height obs
#1: football        f 175.0190  10
#2: football        m 176.6006   7
#3: football        d 174.8258  11
#4: football       gk 173.5069  13
#5: football        w 176.2090   9
```

---

Also, as the example suggests if there is only a single column, then we don't need to specify the `.SDcols` and loop through `lapply`

```
sportset[, .(height = mean(height), obs = .N), .(sport, position)]
```

Comment: @Kauber You might want to review the examples in `?data.table`. A very similar use is covered there, `DT[, c(.N, lapply(.SD, sum)), by=x]`.